# Place video in Smart Object in CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, video

I have an image of an iPhone, where the screen is a Smart Object. I am trying to put a screen recording in the Smart Object, and then to export the image with the video in it as a video.

This is the image I am trying to put the video in:

[image]

This is what I have tried (on Mac):

1. Open the Smart Object in its own tab by double clicking the layer
2. Drag the video into the Smart Object and save
3. Return to the main image, and notice that the screen has indeed updated to show a still frame of the video
4. File > Export > Render Video...

This is what the window that pops up looks like:

[image: Render video window]

As you can see, Photoshop is trying to export the file as a `jpg`, but I am trying to export the video. Indeed, when I press `Render`, a single still `jpg` is spit out.

How can I export a video instead of an image?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm sorry if this comment doesn't answer to your question, but, working on a Mac, why don't you do that in iMovie? It's much more intuitive than Photoshop to edit videos. With the static iPhone image, make a window mask and place the video in.

Comment: @Danielillo, wouldn't using iMovie mean that the video might not *exactly* go over the Smart Object whereas using Photoshop means that the video is exactly covering the right area?

Comment: In iMovie you can create a perfect mask where to place the video, in fact the mask you will make it in Photoshop taking as reference the smart object.

Comment: @Danielillo, how does one do that? Is there a tutorial/example already online somewhere?

Comment: Search for "mask iMovie", [here a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gmxVT9SK8Y)

Comment: @Danielillo, I meant about using the smart object as a reference. I know how to simply add a mask, but I can't get it to be perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82991/discussion-between-danielillo-and-daniel).

Comment: @Danielillo, sure. Also, I added the image to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Inserting and cropping a video in iMovie**

The number 2 is the image transformed in a MP4 movie and repeated as a frozen frame. Saving the image as a .gif from Photoshop and converting it in a .MP4 video file using an online converter.

The number 1 is the video.

[image: iMovie]

Selecting the video frames, change the video size from **Cutaway** > **Picture in picture**

[image: Video Crop]

Comment: The image and video resolutions go down a lot when I drag them into iMovie. Why would this be happening?

Comment: I guess is the preview, see when you export it how it looks

Comment: It’s also low when I export. I think the image is causing the problems because the video is at the correct quality until I do picture in picture.

Comment: Did you choose file optimal quality and compression better quality? My bob sponge video looks perfect :-) (76,6 MB)

Comment: When I change it from Cutaway to Picture in picture, the resolution of both the video and the image go down drastically. Also, did you do anything to turn the image into a repeated MP4 video?

Comment: Answer updated. I can not share my video but looks perfect: 00.15 duration, 76,6 MB.

Comment: I tried your gif way, and while it does look better, the resolution is still not as good as it should be. I'll keep trying other options. Thanks for the help.